# Cleaning single Column within pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Importing a CSV as a pandas dataframe and dropping all completely empty columns:

```
import pandas as pd 

df1 = pd.read_csv("name.csv") 
df1 = df1.dropna(axis=1,how='all')
```

Alas one Column looks like:

```
'Background\r\n * find it: IDE-3: Some Name\r\n * Dokument: SomeName.pptx\r\n * Field: TEG-33\r\n  * happy: Done\r\n\r\nh3. Definition\r\n\r\n\xa0tbd.\r\nh3. exists\r\n\r\ncsv\r\nh3. Source\r\n\r\ncsv?\r\n\r\npotentiell?\r\n\r\ntbd\r\nh3. task\r\n\r\ntbd\r\n\r\n\xa0'
```

**Question1**: I would like to remove all \r\n and \r\n\r\ and \r\n\r\n\ and \r\n\r\n\xa0, etc. Can anyone help with a regex? I cannot find a clear pattern.

**Question2**: How to prevent all these various forms of \r\n\r\ (see question 2) to be written while importing the CSV into a pandas data frame in the first place?

After cleaning all rows of the mentioned column in the data frame the end result should like
[image]

(Python 3, Anaconda3 Distribution, on Windows 10)

Answer (score 1):

For question 1:

```
(df1['Column 3']
.str.replace('\r','')
.str.replace('\n','')
.str.replace('\xa0', ''))
```

For question 2: You could clean that data as it goes into the csv - but hard to say without knowing where the data comes from!

Comment: Data are coming from Jira Tickets, using Python API. Thanks for the answer of question 1

Answer (score 1):

#### Question 1

This regex will achieve what you want:

```
(\r\n)+(\r)*(\xa0)*
```

Explanation:

```
(\r\n)+  # One or more copies of '\r\n'
(\r)*    # Any extra appended    '\r'
(\xa0)*  # Any final appended    '\xao'
```

Though note that in your example there are no strings of the form `\r\n...\r` i.e. with a final appended `\r`.